# Array to separate object

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to convert below array to mentioned separate objects. These are polygon coordinates from twitter. I am getting the tweet locations and want to store somewhere in a separate object. But this array is coming from Twitter API is little different.

```
<script>
[
    [76.70535130773267, 30.70314577305184],
    [76.70535130773267, 30.70314577305184],
    [76.70535130773267, 30.70314577305184],
    [76.70535130773267, 30.70314577305184]
]
[
    [76.515454, 30.569094],
    [76.860158, 30.569094],
    [76.860158, 30.938966],
    [76.515454, 30.938966]
]

[{
        lat: 30.569094,
        lng: 76.515454
    },
    {
        lat: 30.569094,
        lng: 76.860158
    },
    {
        lat: 30.938966,
        lng: 76.860158
    },
    {
        lat: 30.938966,
        lng: 76.515454
    }
], [{
        lat: 30.70314577305184,
        lng: 76.70535130773267
    },
    {
        lat: 30.70314577305184,
        lng: 76.70535130773267
    },
    {
        lat: 30.70314577305184,
        lng: 76.70535130773267
    },
    {
        lat: 30.70314577305184,
        lng: 76.70535130773267
    }
]
```

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Array.reduce()`

```js
var arr = [
    [76.70535130773267, 30.70314577305184],
    [76.70535130773267, 30.70314577305184],
    [76.70535130773267, 30.70314577305184],
    [76.70535130773267, 30.70314577305184]
];

var result = arr.reduce((a,curr)=>{
  a.push({
    "lat" : curr[1],
    "lng" : curr[0]
  });
  return a;
},[]);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Yeah got it. How you are using it in a proper way. I tried with array reduce but I think i was using it in wrong way. Thanks

Comment: @PardipBhatti happy to help you :-)

Comment: Amrinder I tried to vote for you. but it is not letting me do that because I don't have a reputation score more than 15.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```js
let arr = [[[76.70535130773267, 30.70314577305184],[76.70535130773267, 30.70314577305184],[76.70535130773267, 30.70314577305184],[76.70535130773267, 30.70314577305184]],[[76.515454, 30.569094],[76.860158, 30.569094],[76.860158, 30.938966],[76.515454, 30.938966]]];
let result = arr.map(a => a.map(([lng, lat]) => ({lat, lng})));
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I was trying with array reduce but not getting the exact result. But you solved it. Thanks. I can't vote you due to less reputation score

Comment: @PardipBhatti - Glad to help you :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `map` to convert the array of arrays into an array of objects.

```js
var arr = [
  [76.70535130773267, 30.70314577305184],
  [76.70535130773267, 30.70314577305184],
  [76.70535130773267, 30.70314577305184],
  [76.70535130773267, 30.70314577305184]
]

var result = arr.map(([lat, lng]) => ({lat,lng}))

console.log(result);
```